# default button switcher by using event listener

Tags: apache-flex, event-listener

I tried to make the nearest button to the clicked text input default. For this purpose, I wrote the below code.

Firstly, why is my buttonSwitcher function following behind the MouseEvent.CLICK ?
Secondly, Is there better way to do this ?

Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="addListeners()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function addListeners():void {
                a.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonSwitcher);
                b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonSwitcher);
            }

            public function buttonSwitcher(event:MouseEvent):void {

                form.defaultButton = (((event.currentTarget as TextInput).id == "a") ? aButton : bButton); 

            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Panel>
        <mx:Form id="form">
            <mx:FormItem label="a" direction="horizontal">
                <mx:TextInput id="a" />
                <mx:Button id="aButton" label="aButton" />
            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:FormItem label="b" direction="horizontal">
                <mx:TextInput id="b" />
                <mx:Button id="bButton" label="bButton" />
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Form>
    </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ht ecapture phase of the event to change the buttons and maybe use the FocusEvent instead of CLICK, then you also switch buttons when use "tabs" through inputfields:

```
private function addListeners():void
{
    a.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, buttonSwitcher, true);
    b.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, buttonSwitcher, true);
}

public function buttonSwitcher(event:FocusEvent):void 
{
    form.defaultButton = (((event.currentTarget as TextInput).id == "a") ? aButton : bButton); 
}
```

Comment: it's because the changing of the defaultButton comes too late. when the form (or any of its children) gets the focus, it'll 'update' the defaultButton (you can have more than one defaultButton on a page). your eventlistener is called second after the update already happened. by catching the event in the capture phase (third argument true), you change the defaultButton before the rest (update of the page's defaultButton) is run ...